# If the government obtains property through a tax lien, does the homeowner's association contract make it through?

Tags: contract-law, homeownership

If a person owns (100%) a property and is subject to a homeowner's association (HA) contract, but defaults on taxes, after which the property is sold via a tax lien sale, does the HA contract become null, and that property is no longer bound to the HA?

Comment: I suspect not, but the details likely depend on the jurisdiction.

Comment: @phoog That's my guess. Would be interesting to have examples of either way.

Comment: Homeowner Associations carry, generally, deed restrictions. No matter who owns the property it is subject to the HOA. Some HOAs may be voluntary contracts in which case each homeowner can decide. I didn't make this an answer because there may be jurisdictions or examples where this is not the case but I don't know of any. HOA law is at least state specific.

Comment: @DaveDSo with a deed restriction, even the government would be bound by their terms, and so would any following owners?

Comment: @AdamD - Any following owners would be subject to the HOA terms. Local laws would determine if the government would be responsible. I don't know if a tax lien sale actually results in the property transfer from the defaulting party to the government to the buying property or directly from the defaulting party to the buying party.

Comment: I *think* the buyer buys direct from the defaulting party.